# Why is my second order delta sigma encoder implementation not working?

Tags: audio, signal-processing

I wrote the following pseudo code. It implements a [first order delta sigma encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-sigma_modulation#Relationship_to_.CE.94-modulation) :

```
float in[N];
float out[N];
float acc = 0.0f;

for(i = 1 ; i < N ; i++)
{
    acc += in[i] - out[i - 1];

    if(acc > 0)
       out[i] = 1;
    else
       out[i] = -1;
}
```

Here is the schema that I used as reference :

[image]

I implemented it and tested it.  It works, altought it produce a lot of high pitched noise.
To reduce the noise, I adapted code to and tried to wrote a [second order delta sigma encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-sigma_modulation#2nd_order_and_higher_order_modulator)

Here is schema from wiki and code I wrote :

[image]

```
float in[N];    
float out[N];

float acc = 0.0f;
float acc2 = 0.0f;

for(i = 1 ; i < N ; i++)
{
    acc += in[i] - out[i - 1];
    acc2 += acc - out[i];

    if(acc2 > 0)
       out[i] = 1;
    else
       out[i] = -1;
}
```

But it does work at all. The output signal / sound is totally inaudible and total garbage. I have not been able to find what is wrong.

Comment: That seems really cool, what tools do you use to test it?

Comment: I use [Evaldraw](http://www.advsys.net/Ken/download.htm) in 1D mode. [Here is the script](http://pastebin.com/y6yheDMx). You have to copy this to a `.kc` file and open it fromthe tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `out[i]` before you generate it.

Instead of `acc2 += acc - out[i];`, you need `acc2 += acc - out[i-1];`

The `-1` is because the quantizer + DAC together produce a 1 sample delay (in addition to the quantization noise).

Comment: There was indeed an error there. Now it produce sound, but noise is much louder (I expected the opposite)

Comment: A delta-sigma encoder is supposed to produce a lot of high frequency noise.  You're supposed to do it at a very high sampling rate, so that the high frequency noise is inaudible and can be filtered out.  2nd order does indeed produce more high frequency noise than 1st order, but it makes less low-frequency noise so there's less noise left after filtering.  Also, your modulator is not quite stable, as you can see by the noise at the end when the signal is 0.  Real life implementations are not quite as simple as yours -- the integrators have carefully designed transfer functions.